# How to identify the columns that contain non-time dependent variables in a panel data.frame in R?

Tags: r

I want to build a function that can find the column names of the variables that have the same value in all the rows grouped by each ID.

Any ideas how can I do this?

```
example_data <- data.frame(ID = c(1,1,1,2,2,2,3,3,3,3), Age = c(1,2,3,1,2,3,1,2,3,4), Sex = factor(c("m","m","m", "f", "f", "f", "m","m","m","m" )))

    ID Age Sex
1   1   1   m
2   1   2   m
3   1   3   m
4   2   1   f
5   2   2   f
6   2   3   f
7   3   1   m
8   3   2   m
9   3   3   m
10  3   4   m

function_that_finds_the_names(example_data)
```

the output should be a character vector result:

```
[1] "ID"  "Sex"
```

I tried this

```
function_that_finds_the_names <- function(example_data){
    list <- split(example_data, as.factor(example_data$ID), drop = TRUE)
    z <- lapply(list, function(x) names(which(sapply(x, function(x) length(unique(x))) == 1))) 
    return(z)
}

function_that_finds_the_names(example_data)
$`1`
[1] "ID"  "Sex"

$`2`
[1] "ID"  "Sex"

$`3`
[1] "ID"  "Sex"
```

returns a list with the names for each id, but how to extract from there one vector that has the same names in each list element?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We assume that what is wanted is those column names whose columns are constant within ID.

The code in the question works if you replace the `return(z)` line with:

```
Reduce(intersect, z)
```

We will discuss a different approach.  For each column name get the two column data frame consisting only of the `ID` column and that column.  Use `unique` to remove duplicated rows and if there are any duplicated `ID` values in what is left then exclude that column. No packages are used.

```
find_names <- function(data, ID = "ID") {
  const_in_id <- function(x) !anyDuplicated(unique(data[c(ID, x)])[[ID]])
  Filter(const_in_id, names(data))
}


find_names(example_data)
## [1] "ID"  "Sex"
```

Comment: Yes this is what I was looking for!

Answer (score 0):

Is this what you want?

```r
function_that_finds_the_names <- function(example_data){
  list <- split(example_data, as.factor(example_data$ID), drop = TRUE)
  z <- lapply(list, function(x) names(which(sapply(x, function(x) length(unique(x))) == 1))) 
  return(Reduce(intersect, unique(z)))
}
str(function_that_finds_the_names(example_data))
#  chr [1:2] "ID" "Sex"
```

The `return(Reduce(intersect, unique(z)))` will handle if your list is of variable length.

Answer (score 0):

You can do the following using `data.table`. The function also takes different `group` variables.

```
name_fn = function(dt, group){

  require(data.table); setDT(dt)

  tempdt = dt[, lapply(.SD, function(x) length(unique(x))), keyby = group]
  return(c(group, names(which(colSums(tempdt) == nrow(tempdt)))))

}
```

Output:

```
> name_fn(example_data, 'ID')
[1] "ID"  "Sex"
```